# Virtual PC 2007 as programming environment

Tags: development-environment, virtual-pc

I'd like to create a VM in Virtual PC 2007 for use as a development environment/sandbox for an existing ASP.NET application in Visual Studio 2005/SQL Server 2005 (and VSS for source control).

I'm thinking that I need to create a 'base' copy of the environment (with the os, Visual Studio, and Sql Server), and then copy that to a 'work' version that I do actual development in. I would be sharing this VM with one or two other developers who would be working on different parts of the app.

Is this a good idea? What is the best way to get my app/databases in and out of the VM and the changes I make into VSS? Is it just a copy from the host location to the VM share and back again? How do I keep everything synchronized?

Thanks!

Comment: why did you decide to use VM for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bad idea, if you think there's a need for it.

I do something similar when I need to develop a Windows App because it's just nice to have a clean environment. That way I don't accidentally add a reference to something that's not necessarily included in the .NET Framework.  It forces me to install any 3rd party components as I'm developing and documenting.  This way, I can anticipate prerequisites, and ensure that I have them documented before I load software to a user's PC and wonder why it doesn't work.

Just make sure the PC it's hosted on can handle the additional load.  My main Dev PC is a dual core processor with 4GB RAM.  I devote 2GB to any virtual PC I plan on using as a development environment so that I don't hit too much of a performance snag.

As for keeping everything synchronized, you will want to use some sort of source control (as you should even in a normal environment).  (I like SVN with Tortoise SVN as my client of choice, but there are plenty of alternatives.)  Just treat the virtual PCS as if they were normal PCs.  Make sure they can access the network, so you can all access your source code repository.

Answer (score 2):

I would seriously suggest you the following things:

1. Use a "server" solution, rather than a desktop solution. That's far more reasonable if you want to share the VM environment with other developers.
2. Use VMware's products rather than Microsoft's.

From these two points it follows that you should use VMware ESX Server and related products. If you don't want to / can't invest money in it there's a free version of this product: http://www.vmware.com/go/getesxi/, but I never used it.

Whether you choose to use the enterprise version of ESX server or the free version, I suggest you put your IT organization's IT department on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the snapshot feature (or whatever it is called) - that chagnes to the "system" are saved to a delta file so that you can easily revert to an earlier state of the virtual pc. It has some performance penalty. This way you don't have to keep base and work copies.

Answer (score 1):

I use Virtual PCs for all of my Windows development.  The company I work for has legacy products in FoxPro and current products in .NET so I have 2 environments set up:
1 - Windows XP with Foxpro and VSS - I can access VSS directly from this image and the code never enters other machines in my network (I work remotely)
2 - Windows 7 with VS2008 and all the associated bits and pieces needed to develop our .NET software (including TFS).  This is the machine I use every day - I have a meaty desktop PC so I I am able to give the VPC 4GB RAM and runs as fast as a 'normal' PC.

I have my VPCs running in VirtualBox and it is equally as good as the other offerings.  A previous answer mentioned VMWare ESX which is an excellent product for large scale deployment but if you want a server solution then VMWare Server is free and is a nice virtualisation platform.

If you are looking at ways to experiment with changes and still want to use VPC then undo disks are excellent - you fire up the machine, hack away to your hearts content and when you shut down you can choose to save or discard the entire session.

For me Virtual PCs are an excellent way to quickly set-up / tear down development environments and I would struggle to return to using a single machine for all my work.